# How can I write Probability of A given B(Wrong) with mathematical formulas

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I have Two question A and B. I see that given a correct answer to question A correlate with question B. And I see that given a correct answer to A the probability of given a correct answer to B decrease.

I am trying to write Probability of A given B(wrong) or correct but I don't Know the symbol.

> P(A|B) = 0.8

This is to say probability of A give B I would like to write probability of A given B (Wrong) someone know how I can set that syntax? Where B has a boolean answer.

```
P(A|B(wrong answer))
```

This is what I would like to write but with a Symbol instead of writing B (wrong answer))

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Do you mean something like $P(A\,|\,B^c)$?  Where $B^c$ refers to the complement of $B$ (that is, the event that $B$ does not occur).

Comment: Does this answer your question?  [1591009](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1591009/192634)

Comment: The following notation is also often used: $\mathbb{P}(A\, \vert \, \neg B)$.

Comment: Besides the notation suggestions by Nils (and here you could also use a minus sign in front of $B)$ and lulu, you could also simply write $P(A\,|\,{\text {not-}}B),$ which works well when you don't have math symbols, superscripts, etc. available (such as basic ASCII email) or you're writing to someone who might not know your notation for complement (which can vary) or negation.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{array}{|c|}
\hline
A& B & \mathrm{Prob.}\\ \hline
0& 0 & a \\ \hline
0& 1 & b \\ \hline
1& 0 & c \\ \hline
1& 1 & d \\ \hline
\end{array}

You can assume $0$ to mean wrong answer and $1$ to mean right answer. The table above fully describes the probability distribution on all possible scenarios. Now,

$$P(A=1|B=0) = d$$

Comment: Instead of $P(A=1|B=1) = d,$ I think you want $P(A=1|B=0) = d.$

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks, made the corresponding correction.